# What is igrid server - port 19000?

Tags: linux, networking, unix, port, service

Recently our monitoring tools is reporting a port as down, the port number is 19000.

I have never seen this port before and I don't find out good information. Doing some tests, I've seen I can telnet it using localhost, but not ipaddres/hostname:

```
[root@server01 ~]# telnet 10.122.96.60 19000
Trying 10.122.96.84...
telnet: connect to address 10.122.96.60: Connection refused
[root@server01 ~]# telnet localhost 19000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Also, it is used by some java process and informix database:

```
[root@server01 ~]# lsof -iTCP:19000

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    14492 java_user   93u  IPv6 133689854      0t0  TCP localhost:38902->localhost:igrid (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25235 informix   12u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25277 informix    3u  IPv4  33431811      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid (LISTEN)
oninit  25277 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25278 informix    7u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25280 informix    4u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25281 informix    4u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25282 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25283 informix   11u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25284 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25285 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25286 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25289 informix    6u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25290 informix   12u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25291 informix   12u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25292 informix   12u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
oninit  25315     root    5u  IPv4  33431811      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid (LISTEN)
oninit  25319     root   22u  IPv4 133689855      0t0  TCP localhost:igrid->localhost:38902 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What is this? How can I allow this port for remote connections (our monitoring tool)? Recently the server has migrated from physical machine to virtual machine and now the monitoring tool cannot reach this port.

The `/etc/services` has:

```
igrid           19000/tcp               # iGrid Server
igrid           19000/udp               # iGrid Server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ss` and `ps` commands to check further. Example of output, replace 12345 with your PID:

```
$ sudo ss -lntp | grep :19000
LISTEN  0  128  127.0.0.1:19000  0.0.0.0:*  users:(("program-name",pid=12345,fd=62))

$ sudo ps aux | grep 12345
oioki  12345  0.4  1.9 5132596 238256 ?  Sl  09:33  3:06 /full/path/to/your/program-name
```